# Why my index fields are still shown as "analyzed" even after i index em as "not_analyzed"

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a lot of data (json format) in Amazon SQS. I basically have a simple python script which pulls data from the SQS queue & then indexes it in ES. My problem is even though i have specified in my script to index as "not_analyzed", i still see my index filed as "analyzed" in index setting of kibana4 dashboard

Here is my python code :

```
doc = {
      "settings" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1
       },
    "mappings" : {
     "type_name": {
       "dynamic_templates": [
         {
           "strings": {
             "match_mapping_type": "string",
           "mapping": {
             "type": "string",
             "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
         }
        }
       ]
      }
     }
   }
es = Elasticsearch()
h = { "Content-type":"application/json" }
res = requests.request("POST","http://localhost:9200/"+index_name+"/",headers=h,data=json.dumps(doc))
post = es.index(index=index_name , doc_type='server' , id =1 , body=json.dumps(new_list))
print "------------------------------"
print "Data Pushed Successfully to ES"
```

I am not sure what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc_type` you're using when indexing (= `server`) doesn't match the one you have in your index mappings (= `type_name`).

So if you index your documents like this instead, it will work

```
post = es.index(index=index_name , doc_type='type_name' , id =1 , body=json.dumps(new_list))
                                                 ^
                                                 |
                                            change this
```